# Is it necessary to use GROUP BY when we are selecting an aggregate function on a column in addition to a column without an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm getting an error that is:

> "Column 'Weather.cityName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Why here is necessary to use `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT cityName , MAX (highTemperature) As highTemperature
FROM Weather
WHERE cityName = 'Rawalpindi';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it necessary to use `GROUP BY`.  You have an aggregation query where you want to return one row per city -- even if there is only one city.  That makes your query an aggregation query.  You can adjust the query so it is not needed.  Here are two methods:

```
SELECT MAX(cityName) as cityName, MAX(highTemperature) As highTemperature
FROM Weather
WHERE cityName = 'Rawalpindi';
```

Or:

```
SELECT 'Rawalpindi' as cityName, MAX(highTemperature) As highTemperature
FROM Weather
WHERE cityName = 'Rawalpindi';
```

Both of these are valid aggregation queries with no `GROUP BY`.  As such, they will return exactly one row -- even if no rows match the `WHERE` clause.  Instead of `CityName`, they use either an aggregation function or a constant, so there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allows to use such syntax:

> [MySQL Handling of GROUP
>   BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)
>
> **SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature
>   T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns:** If such a
>   relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This
>   would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of
>   customers.
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

```
SELECT cityName , MAX(highTemperature) As highTemperature
FROM Weather
WHERE cityName IN('Rawalpindi', 'Delphi');
-- In aggregated query without GROUP BY,
-- expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cityName';
-- this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT cityName , MAX(highTemperature) As highTemperature
FROM Weather
WHERE cityName = 'Rawalpindi';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bb5e21905ef1e2a198f0eb0a51c46d9)**